# C++ template overload resolution called from template function pick candidate declared after template instantiation

Tags: c++, templates, overload-resolution

Here is a minimalist example of a very strange overload resolution from a template context:

```
#include <iostream>

// Types //
struct I { int v; };

template <class T>
struct D { T t; };

// Functions //

// Overload 1
template <class T>
I f(T) { return {1}; }

// Template indirection that calls f(T)
template <class T>
I g(D<T>) { return f(T{}); }

// Non template indirection that calls f(T)
I h(D<I>) { return f(I{}); }

int main() {
    std::cout
        << f(I{}).v     // f(I{}) overload called directly
        << "\n"         //    => overload 1 called
        << h(D<I>{}).v  // f(I{}) called though non-template
        << "\n"         //    => overload 1 called
        << g(D<I>{}).v  // f(I{}) called though template
        << "\n";        //    => overload 2 actually called ???
}

// Overload 2
// Should not be reachable as declared after all f(...) calls.
// If was a candidate, would be chosen over 1.
I f(I) { return {2}; }
```

This seem to be related to [ADL](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) because if `I` is placed in a namespace "overload 1" is always called.

I know that ADL is performed as if the call was made from the template instantiation point (`main`).

> For a dependent name used in a template definition, the lookup is postponed until the template arguments are known, at which time ADL examines function declarations with external linkage (until C++11) that are visible from the template definition context as well as in the template instantiation context, while non-ADL lookup only examines function declarations with external linkage (until C++11) that are visible from the template definition context.
>   http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup#Template_definition

But here "Overload 2" is declared AFTER `main`! `main` being the instanciation point of `g` and `f`, I assumed only function declared *before* `main` would be overload candidates.

Note that this behaviour is related to `g` being template as `h` (`g`'s equivalent not template function) calls "Overload 1".

**How can "overload 2" -being declared after `main`- ever be called ?**

This behaviour has been reproduced with clang++ (3.8.1) and g++ (6.2.1).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[[temp.dep.candidate]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.dep.candidate#1):

> If the call would be ill-formed or would find a better match had the
>   lookup within the associated namespaces considered all the function
>   declarations with external linkage introduced in those namespaces in
>   all translation units, not just considering those declarations found
>   in the template definition and template instantiation contexts, then
>   the program has undefined behavior.

Moreover, [[temp.point]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.point#8), emphasis mine:

> A specialization for a function template [...] may have multiple
>   points of instantiations within a translation unit, and in addition to
>   the points of instantiation described above, for any such
>   specialization that has a point of instantiation within the
>   translation unit, **the end of the translation unit is also considered a
>   point of instantiation**. [...] If two different points of instantiation
>   give a template specialization different meanings according to the
>   one-definition rule ([basic.def.odr]), the program is ill-formed, no
>   diagnostic required.

The behavior of your program is undefined.

Comment: That adds yet an other stone against adding overloads in the namespace of a library. Such addition may result in undefined behaviour if this overload could have be chosen in the library code. Knew the rule, not its rational.